# Understanding RACSubject

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Im studying Reactive Cocoa and i wonder why following not work:

In class B i declare:

```
+(RACSubject*)importText{

    RACSubject *subject = [RACSubject subject];


    //1 block

    NSArray *testArray = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];

    //2 block

    [subject sendNext:[[[testArray rac_sequence] map:^id(NSString* value) {

        return [value stringByAppendingString:@"More"];
    }] array]];



    return subject;
}
```

In class A:

```
 [[SecondObject importText] subscribeNext:^(id x) {

       NSLog(@"Output is %@", x);
   }];
```

However, nothing output in a console. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look close to what `importText` method does. You first created a subject and temporary array. And then before any other stuffs happen, you just call `sendNext:...` to send the value you temporary created but no one else haven't subscribed the subject yet. And finally your `importText` method returns the subject which `SecondObject` will get and then subscribes to it.

```
@interface SomeClass
@property (nonatomic, strong) RACSubject *subject;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.subject = [RACSubject subject];
    }
}

- (RACSubject *)rac_signalForImportText
{
    return self.subject;
}

- (void)importText
{
    NSArray *testArray = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];

    //2 block

    [subject sendNext:[[[testArray rac_sequence] map:^id(NSString* value) {

        return [value stringByAppendingString:@"More"];
    }] array]];
}



SomeClass* Second = [SomeClass alloc] init];
[[Second rac_signalForImportText] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
     NSLog(@"Output is %@", x);
}];
[Second importText];
```

I'm not sure why you want to use a subject in this way, but notice `rac_signalForImportText` won't get called until `importText` method call because that is where I use the subject to call `sendNext` which will trigger whoever subscribes on `rac_signalForImportText`. Hope this help.